# building an apk in phonegap with database connectivity(postgresql) in netbeans 8.0

Tags: html5-canvas

I created html/js/css application in netbeans 8.0. Then i build it in adobe phonegap. But after building an .apk file, it can not connects to the database i.e. postgresql. I use json for calling servlet which is in netbeans 8.0 src package. so please tell me how i connect to the database & get response in my mobile apk.